# Azure APIM: error when configuring APIM in internal mode

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to configure APIM in internal mode using the instructions from this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-internal-vnet?tabs=stv2#enable-vnet-connection. However, after completing the necessary steps and clicking "Save", I encountered the following error:

> Failed to update API Management service hostnames Invalid parameter:
> Public IP Address resource
> /subscriptions/cb9f3d5f-937b-4ba3-93b6-e66f6ba90501/resourceGroups/default/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/earth-da-dev-ip
> must have a Fully qualified domain name of the A DNS record associated
> with the public IP. Refer to document aka.ms/azurestandardpublicip
>
> Correlation ID: a7f6588c-dcb9-46e3-9451-6e544ef17e6c

Can someone explain to me in simple terms what this means? My ultimate objective is to give my APIM instance a private virtual IP address since it currently only has a public Virtual IP (VIP) addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself here:

Just do not fill in the "Management public ip address".
Just leave it blank and click "Apply"

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I had to specify a domain name in the IP address details > Configuration > DNS name label (optional)

Once specified I could create the API Management Instance.